# MYSQL [USER TABLE modification brings Errors]

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, create-table

I am trying to follow a simple lesson in web tourist.
I tried to modify the code given for my needs.
And it spits error with modification:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''id'), UNIQUE KEY ('email'), KEY ('email', 'pass') ) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT ' at line 13

ORIG CODE:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` ( 
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
`username` varchar(30) NOT NULL default '', 
`password` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '', 
`email` varchar(40) NOT NULL default '', 
`msn` varchar(250) NOT NULL default 'Not Specified', 
`aim` varchar(250) NOT NULL default 'Not Specified', 
`location` varchar(36) NOT NULL default 'Not Specified', 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
) TYPE=MyISAM;
```

MY EDIT:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
type ENUM( 'member' , 'admin' ) NOT NULL ,
`username` varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
`password` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`first_name` varchar (15) NOT NULL,
`last_name` varchar (30) NOT NULL,
`gender` ENUM('male',  'female') NOT NULL default 'male',
`email` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
`skype` varchar(50) NOT NULL default 'Not Specified',
`facebook` varchar(150) NOT NULL default 'Not Specified',
`location` varchar(100) NOT NULL default 'Not Specified',
PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
UNIQUE KEY ('email'),
KEY ('email', 'pass')
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up back-ticks and quotes. This is the general rule to live by: back-ticks are used to enclose table structure (table names, table columns, constraint names etc). Quotation marks are used to enclose row ***values*** - aka, the actual data that is being entered into the table. You won't use quotation marks in a DDL statement unless you are specifying default ***values***.

Your error is on primary, unique and index keys in your statement.

```
PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
UNIQUE KEY ('email'),
KEY ('email', 'pass')
```

Should be (notice the back-ticks):

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY (`email`),
KEY (`email`, `password`)
```

Note also that your index is referring to a non-existent column `pass` - I've changed it to the correct column `password`.

Answer (score 1):

You gone mad with the backticks

```
default '',
```

Two single quotes is empty string
BackTicks  are for  column names and such e.g.

> `My Strange column name`

Comment: Edited. Please check the description again!

Comment: So you fixed the backticks round the defaults, but you now have single quotes round the field names isn your keys as mentioned by @Perception. Strings are single quotes, objects (columns , tables etc) are backticks.